# AdMob using diffrent banner for one app

Tags: android, android-activity, admob

I am using admob in my android apps to get a little money,in my apps I use mostly a top banner, but I'm wondering do I create a banner for each activity or only one banner for all the activities ? and if that can touch the earned money so which technic I use to get more money than the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't using the same layout containing the banner for all activities, you'd have to define the banners for each activity's layout.

To maximize revenue, you should place one banner on each activity, set the refresh rate between 45 - 60 seconds and use ad mediation. Check [this out](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2954259?hl=en) for more

Importantly, make sure you follow the official implementation [dos and don'ts](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2790280?hl=en) so you don't get your account banned.

Comment: I use the same layout so I can use the same banner in all the activities, but I want to get the more revenue as possible, so like you said I will create a banner for each activity an modify the refresh time, thank's